# Is it possible to run Android SDK using netbeans 7

Tags: android, netbeans, android-2.2-froyo

I am using Eclipse IDE to develop android apps. But I want to use Netbeans IDE for developing Android apps. Android SDK works fine with previous version of Netbeans IDE. But it can not added to Netbeans 7.0 using [Android plugin](http://kenai.com/projects/nbandroid/downloads/download/updatecenter/updates.xml). So, is it possible to run Android SDK using netbeans 7 ???

Any suggestion or tutorial will greatly appreciated.

Comment: may be this helps: [Android Apps on NetBeans 7 – Crash Dummy Guide](http://etapix.com/2011/06/08/android-apps-on-netbeans-7-%E2%80%93-crash-dummy-guide/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After installing Android plugin, to locate Android SDK you have to go to Tools > Options > Misc > Android and select here the location of your SDK.

Answer (score 1):

add the following XML file to your plug in -> setting
http://kenai.com/projects/nbandroid/downloads/download/updatecenter/updates.xml
then download the SDK 
after that you can add your platform to SDK